# Batch file to get the Max Frequency of the Computer

Tags: batch-file, resources, cpu, monitor

If I go to the 'Resource Monitor' on the computer, I can see the 'Maximum Frequency' value. Is there anyway I can get this value by using a batch command?

[image: Resource Monitor]

Comment: No, this isn't possible using just a batch file.

Comment: Ken, I'm trying to determine, via batch, if a computer is getting throttled. I know that if the maximum frequency value is low (less than 80%), I would consider that throttling. Is there a way for a batch script to determine if the computer is throttling the CPU?

Comment: Do you just mean something like `typeperf -sc 1 "\Processor Information(*)\% of Maximum Frequency"` ?

Comment: `wmic cpu get currentclockspeed,maxclockspeed`. Note that `currentclockspeed` may change rapidly and so is most probably  not be an accurate value.

Comment: @AnonCoward and Stephen I tried both methods and I don't see the values matching the screenshot above.